# Multiple readers attempting to update same document in mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a collection of profiles(name: profiles) in a database(name: db) in mongo. Each profile has {`id, lastUpdatedAt, createdAt`} fields. Each profile can be decided to be stale, based on `lastUpdated` field of the profile. If `now_in_millisecs-profile.lastUpdated>30*60*1000`(30 mins), profile is stale.

I have multiple workers(running on diff.machines) who try to grab unused profile and assume that they are owning. All workers try to read `profiles.all()`; Loop through each profile, check for a stale profile and grab it. (if no profile is free, a new profile is created). Each active worker keeps updating lastUpdated at every 30mins (same time window I was checking above)

As I tried this setup, I see multiple workers picking up same stale profile. I guess this is because, all workers see same stale profile and decide to reuse it and everyone gets the same profile name. How can I avoid this in mongodb.

Am I supposed to use Transactions in mongodb(which are not supported directly). Looks like reader writer lock on one document does not help here. I m using spring-mongo-java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do or if this will fix it, but take a look at findAndModify().  It can update the first (stale) doc it find and return it.  Then subsequent checks by other workers will see other docs and not that one.